# Add space after every 4th character

Tags: php

I want to add a space to some output after every 4th character until the end of the string.
I tried:

```
$str = $rows['value'];
<? echo substr($str, 0, 4) . ' ' . substr($str, 4); ?>
```

Which just got me the space after the first 4 characters.

How can I make it show after every 4th ?

Answer (score 111):

You can use [`chunk_split` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php):

```
$str = chunk_split($rows['value'], 4, ' ');
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/WoGKa)

If the length of the string is a multiple of four but you don't want a trailing space, you can pass the result to [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Comment: Taking the question strictly, the OP demands the traling space if it's at the fourth position. However someones dislikes that, I got a downvote, too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11807841/367456

Comment: make it `rtrim($str, ' ')` to be more precise. But it still lacks the problem to remove *any*  trailing spaces.

Comment: True. Well, the OP will know what they want :)

Comment: Sure, I won't nitpick on that level until clarification :). However, I wished the downvoter would have shared. Looks like he/she took back yours, I smell there was some disliking of not using wordwrap, however that's only a wild guess ^^

Answer (score 70):

Wordwrap does exactly what you want:

```
echo wordwrap('12345678' , 4 , ' ' , true )
```

will output:
1234 5678

If you want, say, a hyphen after every second digit instead, swap the "4" for a "2", and the space for a hyphen:

```
echo wordwrap('1234567890' , 2 , '-' , true )
```

will output:
12-34-56-78-90

[Reference - wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

Comment: this is the better answer than `chunk_split` 
because `string` that you are added on every n character also added this `string` in the end of given_string

Answer (score 11):

Have you already seen this function called wordwrap?
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

Here is a solution. Works right out of the box like this.

```
<?php
$text = "Thiswordissoverylong.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 4, "\n", true);
echo "$newtext\n";
?>
```

Comment: That does not insert a space after every fourth character.

Comment: Looks like this does something totally different, http://codepad.org/4uDNeEWl, of five required spaces, only one is in there (and as it looks, only because it was already in the original string).

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example of string with length is not a multiple of 4 (or 5 in my case).

```
function space($str, $step, $reverse = false) {
    
    if ($reverse)
        return strrev(chunk_split(strrev($str), $step, ' '));
    
    return chunk_split($str, $step, ' ');
}
```

Use :

```
echo space("0000000152748541695882", 5);
```

> result: 00000 00152 74854 16958 82

Reverse mode use ("BVR code" for swiss billing) :

```
echo space("1400360152748541695882", 5, true);
```

> result: 14 00360 15274 85416 95882

**EDIT** *2021-02-09*

Also useful for EAN13 barcode formatting :

```
space("7640187670868", 6, true);
```

> result : 7 640187 670868

short syntax version :

```
function space($s=false,$t=0,$r=false){return(!$s)?false:(($r)?trim(strrev(chunk_split(strrev($s),$t,' '))):trim(chunk_split($s,$t,' ')));}
```

Hope it could help some of you.

Answer (score 4):

On way would be to split into 4-character chunks and then join them together again with a space between each part.

As this would technically miss to insert one at the very end if the last chunk would have exactly 4 characters, we would need to add that one manually ([Demo](http://codepad.org/PJ3LWKb0)):

```
$chunk_length = 4;
$chunks = str_split($str, $chunk_length);
$last = end($chunks);
if (strlen($last) === $chunk_length) {
    $chunks[] = '';
}
$str_with_spaces = implode(' ', $chunks);
```

Comment: minified version:  `chunk_split($str, $chunkLength, ' ');`

Answer (score 4):

one-liner:

```
$yourstring = "1234567890";
echo implode(" ", str_split($yourstring, 4))." ";
```

This should give you as output: 
    1234    5678    90

That's all :D

Comment: Sure, and [that has already been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11807841/367456) incl. making visible that if a space is needed after each 4th character as well at the end of the string, this needs some addition. And a tab is not a space but I think you know.

Comment: I had used tabs for the sake of visibility. Now should be enough :D

Comment: As written, I thought you know :)

Answer (score 1):

The function `wordwrap()` basically does the same, however this should work as well.

```
$newstr = '';
$len = strlen($str); 
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $newstr.= $str[$i];
    if (($i+1) % 4 == 0) {
        $newstr.= ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: afaik you should save the value of strlen instead of using it in the for loop because using it in the loop will cause the length of the string to be evaluated with each iteration

Comment: You are right if this is a *very long* string. However it does not take much more time fo short strings. I updated the answer according to your thought anyway.

Answer (score 0):

PHP3 Compatible:

Try this:

```
$strLen = strlen( $str );
for($i = 0; $i < $strLen; $i += 4){
  echo substr($str, $i, 4) . ' ';
} 
unset( $strLen );
```

Comment: The only negative here is the that there will be a trailing space that would need to be removed or otherwise dealt with.

Comment: yeah.. could wrap it in trim() I guess ;)

Comment: Yeah I mean it depends on what he wants.. I think my demo sufficiently illustrates the solution though, no?

Comment: Taking the wording of the question strictly, OP demands the trailing slash. However, you need to output the remainding substring as well which is missing in your answer if I see that right.

Comment: this is all basically academic in any case because he can just use wordwrap, but what "remaining substring" are you referring to?

Comment: ... for those of you still using PHP3, the other answers will not work! hehe ;)

Comment: No wordwrap does not work. I have outlined that in a previous comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807796/add-space-after-every-4th-character/11807841#comment15691923_11807820

Answer (score -3):

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP");
int idx = str.length() - 4;
while (idx > 0){
  str.insert(idx, " ");
  idx = idx - 4;
}
return str.toString();
```

Explanation, this code will add space from right to left:

```
 str = "ABCDEFGH" int idx = total length - 4; //8-4=4
    while (4>0){
        str.insert(idx, " "); //this will insert space at 4th position
        idx = idx - 4; // then decrement 4-4=0 and run loop again
    }
```

The final output will be:

```
ABCD EFGH
```

Comment: this doesn't look like `php`

Comment: Provided code might help, but in order to make it a good answer you should also describe/explain why/how exactly does your code solve the problem.

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.