# Add a space on a string but counting right to left

Tags: php, string, split

Iv seeing some answers like: [Add space after every 4th character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807796/add-space-after-every-4th-character) using

```
echo wordwrap('1234567890' , 4 , '-' , true )
```

But in this case I need to count the characters from right to left.

For example to format a phone number user friendly **123-123-1234**. The problem is that sometimes the user could submit a code area, and If I start normally left to right I can get this: **012-312-3123-4** So I am thinking of starting right to left.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a regular expression with an optional match at the beginning, and anchor it at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex with a lookahead [assertion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) that there are one or more groups of 4 characters between the matched position and the end of the string should do this for you.

```
echo preg_replace("/(?=(.{4})+$)/", "-", "1234567890");
// 12-3456-7890
```

You'll need to handle strings with an exact multiple of 4 characters which will end up with a hyphen at the beginning. You could either add a lookbehind assertion to the regex or it might be easier to read if you trim the hyphen off afterwards.

```
echo preg_replace("/(?=(.{4})+$)/", "-", "123456789012");
// -1234-5678-9012
echo preg_replace("/(?<=.)(?=(.{4})+$)/", "-", "123456789012");
// 1234-5678-9012
echo ltrim(preg_replace("/(?=(.{4})+$)/", "-", "123456789012"), "-");
// 1234-5678-9012
```

Comment: I've realised from reading your question again that although it says you want to add a space after every fourth character counting right to left, your example **123-123-1234** does not do this. Let me know (and edit the question) if I misunderstood the requirements.

Comment: Let me test the options and I'll report the results. I could use a space or character. :o)

Comment: Hum. Now that I have tried your solution and playing with it I am trying to group constructors. For example "preg_replace("/(?=(.{3})(.{4})+$)/", "-", "123456789012")" to explore the spacings. Should I edit the question or post a new one?

Comment: You're almost there. To split every third character except for a last set of four characters, you can do `preg_replace("/(?<=.)(?=(.{3})*(.{4})$)/", "-", "1231231234");` (`(.{3})*` = 0 or more sets of three, followed by exactly one set of four chars); or more simply `preg_replace("/(?<=.)(?=(.{3})+.$)/", "-", "1231231234");` (1 or more sets of three, followed by exactly one character at the end of the string).

Comment: Oh. Great! Regular expressions makes you squeeze the logic of your brain a lot! I must say a geeky comment: "Fascinating" :o). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
function myFormat($s, $len, $delimiter = "-")
{
    $techChar = " ";
    $newLen = ceil(strlen($s) / $len) * $len;

    $s = str_pad($s, $newLen, $techChar, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $s = wordwrap($s, $len, $delimiter, true);
    $s = ltrim($s, $techChar);

    return $s;
}
```

Comment: Let me take a look and do some tests, Thanks :o)