# Grouping in regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I want to explore a bit more on regular expressions. [Add a space on a string but counting right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846404/add-a-space-on-a-string-but-counting-right-to-left)

The result of this regex

```
preg_replace("/(?=(.{3})*(.{4})$)/", "-", "1231231234");
```

is: 123-123-1234

Now, I am experimenting with the quantifiers and groups, but I can not make them to work properly.

Why this (php)

```
preg_replace("/(?=(.{3})*(.{4})(.{4})$)/", "-", "1212312312345678");
```

and this:

```
preg_replace("/(?=(.{3})*(.{4}){2}$)/", "-", "1212312312345678");
```

both give me a big 8 character group as an output

```
12-123-123-12345678
```

I probably expected the result on the second case {2}, but not on the first case.

The expected result I intended was:

```
12-123-123-1234-5678
```

1) What is the the logic on **(.{4})(.{4}) = (.{8})** instead of being 2 diferent events?

2) What would be the proper grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how that regex works. Let me break it down for you:

```
(?=          lookahead assertion: the following pattern must match, but
             will not consume any of the text.
   (.{3})*   matches a series of 3 characters, any number of times. In
             other words, this consumes characters in multiples of 3.
   (.{4})$   makes sure there are exactly 4 characters left.
)
```

This pattern produces an *empty match* in every place where you want to insert a dash `-`. That's why `preg_replace("/(?=(.{3})*(.{4})$)/", "-", "1231231234");` *inserts* dashes in the correct places - replacing the empty string is the same as inserting. Let's look at that step-by-step, using the text `31231234` as an example:

```
         remaining text     remaining pattern      what happens
step 0:  31231234           (.{3})*(.{4})$         (.{3})* matches one time
step 1:  31234              (.{3})*(.{4})$         (.{3})* matches again
step 2:  34                 (.{3})*(.{4})$         (.{3})* fails to match another time
step 3:  34                 (.{4})$                (.{4}) fails to match -> backtrack
step 5:  31234              (.{4})$                (.{4}) fails to match -> pattern failed to
                                                   match, no dash will be inserted.
```

After the pattern failed to match at position 0 in the text, it will be checked again at position 1 (remaining text is `1231234`):

```
         remaining text     remaining pattern      what happens
step 0:  1231234            (.{3})*(.{4})$         (.{3})* matches one time
step 1:  1234               (.{3})*(.{4})$         (.{3})* matches again
step 2:  4                  (.{3})*(.{4})$         (.{3})* fails to match another time
step 3:  4                  (.{4})$                (.{4})$ matches -> dash will be inserted
                                                   here, giving "3-1231234"
```

The same thing happens again 3 characters later, giving the end result `3-123-1234`. In other words, the group `(.{4})$` specifies that no dashes should be inserted in the last 4 characters of the text. By consuming the last 4 characters, it makes it impossible for the pattern to match if there are less than 4 characters remaining. That is why both `(.{4})(.{4})$` and `(.{4}){2}$` produce a block of 8 characters - the pattern can not match if less than 8 characters remain.

In order to insert another dash in the last 8 characters, you have to use two groups of 4 characters `.{4}` and make one of them optional:

```
(?=((.{3})*.{4})?(.{4})$)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. One more question. When using $ is it really a backtrack search from that point or it is some kind of left to right repetitions? For example on this simple test: https://regex101.com/r/eE6zK7/1 it says that the match was found after 20 steps.

Comment: @Rafael: `$` is just an end-of-string anchor, it doesn't affect the "direction" of the regex. If you click on "debugger" on regex101 you can see how it matches step by step.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you are using [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in this case. Unlike normal matching, they don't actually consume what they match.

So in the first example, there are 2 zero-width-matches, the first one after the first `123`, so the lookahead matches for `1231234`, the second after the second `123`, where the lookahead matches `1234`. You might want to use one of the online-regex-testers to see what actually matches, my choice would be [regex101.com](http://regex101.com).

So for your example you have to make the lookahead also match the last 4 digits (and only them), one way to achieve this would be `(?=((.{3})*(.{4}))?(.{4})$)`, making the first part optional.

See it here on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hE1mB7/1).

Comment: Thanks, yes I have being playing with regex101 :o), yes, one thing I neet to understand more is that one pattern matches on other patterns aswell. Ty.

Answer (score 1):

`(?=(.{3})*(.{4}){2}$)` matches every 3xN character sequence with 2x4 = 8 characters at the end, where N >= 0.

To match every 4xN character from the end, where 1 <= N <= 2, or every 3xN character sequence with 8 characters at the end, where N >= 1, use the following:

```
preg_replace("/(?=(.{4}){1,2}$)|(?=(.{3})+.{8}$)/", "-", "1212312312345678");
```

Comment: Iwteresting. For the moment I do not think I will use the vertical bar, but it is a good example thanks.